# How can I get the path to a Windows service executable WITHOUT using sc qc?

Tags: windows, windows-service, windows-command-prompt

I need to query a windows service for the path to it's executable via the command prompt.  I think the way I **would** do this is:`sc qc myServiceName`, but when I do that, I get the following error:

> [SC] QueryServiceConfig FAILED 122:
>
> The data area passed to a system call is too small.
>
> [SC] GetServiceConfig needs 1094 bytes

I think this means that the sc command is sending a data structure to some other library that is too small for the data that needs to be returned.  Instead of SC nicely retrying with a larger data structure (1094 bytes) it bombs out and gives me this ugly error message.  Thanks Micro$oft.

So is there a way to work around this error?  I just need the path to the executable, but will parse it out of some other text if needed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found an workable solution:

`reg query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\<serviceName>" /v "ImagePath"`

Of course this needs some parsing, but it gives me the full path that the services.msc dialog box provides.

Answer (score 25):

I encountered this problem too when trying to get the details of a service where the path to the executable was very long. [This discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/salt-users/roVt-A6xcnQ) contains a workaround; you can pass a buffer size as an argument to `sc qc`. That is, if you do:

```
sc qc <service name> 5000
```

the "data area passed to a system call is too small" error goes away.

---

Also see [SC QC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742055(v=ws.11).aspx) MSDN page:

```
sc [<ServerName>] qc [<ServiceName>] [<BufferSize>]
```

where:

> <BufferSize> Specifies the size (in bytes) of the buffer. The default buffer size is 1,024 bytes.

Comment: FYI, `2^13 = 8192` is the maximum value for the buffer size.

Comment: `sc queryex type= service state= all | find /i "myServiceName` lists all services but unfortunately no path.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this in PowerShell with a WMI query like this:

```
$service = get-wmiobject -query 'select * from win32_service where name="winrm"'; echo $service.pathname
```

This will give you the full path, including options as they are shown in services.msc. Just replace `winrm` in my example with whatever service you want to search for.

The above query for `winrm` should output `C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k NetworkService`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't depend on powershell since XP doesn't have it by default.  I need support for XP, server 2008, and 7, all without installing any additional software.

Comment: @Jared that's too bad. You're unable to run this from a single machine against a bunch of remote machines?

Comment: No this is actually a bit of script to go in the uninstaller for an application.  I figured out a solution that works and added an answer for it though.

Answer (score 8):

Try it using the `wmic` command line utility. Here's an example of a service on my machine called `CrashPlanService`.

```
C:\Users\Ben>wmic service CrashPlanService get PathName

PathName
"C:\Program Files\CrashPlan\CrashPlanService.exe"
```

Basically, `wmic service <<YourService>> get PathName`.

Comment: Doesn't quite work.  But, on the other hand, this works:  "wmic service | find "<servicename>"

Comment: @djangofan what output do you get, and with which service? Maybe you've got a different version of `wmic` (I'm on Windows 7 SP1)?

Comment: @Ben Pilbrow That didn't work for me either.  wmic isn't getting the path name (just returns "PathName" with nothing on the following line).  Not sure if this is because there are a lot of parameters embedded in the path making it very long.

Comment: worked for me but i had to process the result a little: ((wmic service SQLBrowser get PathName) -match "`"")[0].replace("`"", "")

Comment: `wmic service` works great. Lists all services with their paths.

Comment: If you need to see `path to Executable` of specific windows service then it works charm. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Starting from PowerShell 7 :

```
(Get-Service theServiceName).BinaryPathName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$binpath = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<serviceName>).ImagePath
$binpath = ($binpath).Substring(1,($binpath).IndexOf("<serviceBinFileName>")-1)
```

Comment: If you are already using powershell, why not just use `(get-service <servicename>).BinaryPathName`?

Comment: FWIW, the `BinaryPathName` property is only available as of PowerShell 7.0.  It is not available in PS 5.1.